# What database in Thermo-Calc should I use if I am trying to model Yttrium Hydrides?

Tags: thermo-calc

I am a new user of thermo-calc and I am currently trying to model the phase diagrams of Yttrium Hydride.  I have a couple samples doped with different elements (for example, Li).  The only database I can find on thermo-Calc that can handle both Li and Y is Pure5, however, when I used Pure5, it said the only phase it claimed was present was the gas phase.  Does anyone know of a different database to use or potential errors I may be making due to inexperience?

Comment: Well, the ASM Alloy Phase Diagram database has no entry for Li-Y. A nominal diagram is given by Okamoto in Journal of Phase Equilibria and Diffusion volume 30, page216 (2009). I have not found a good Calphad assessment of Li-Y, although one could estimate from that diagram.  A thermodynamic assessment of Y-H can be found in Fu, Progress in Natural Science: Materials International 28 (2018) 332–336. Some info on Li-H can be pulled from Pelton, Zeitschrift fur Metallkunde 84(11) 767-772 (1993), and references therein.